# How to get hardware info (especially GPU) in order to use Golang on Linux

Tags: linux, gpu, golang

I need to collect all GPUs' info of a Linux server (such as VRAM, clock speed, usage, model name, etc., ...) in order to use Go (AKA Golang).

I tried `hwinfo` and `lspci`, it just shows limited information. Is it possible to use some package, or something, can get full information like `nvidia-smi` shows?

Comment: Visit the following URL. https://github.com/himidori/go-hwinfo-parser you will get all the information.

Comment: Are you saying that: you need this information before you use Go, or; that you wish to access this information from *within*, or using, Go?

Comment: I don't see why you need that information to be able to use Go.  It is unclear what the connection between a system's clock speed and the ability to run Go on that system is. Also, what is "usage" and what else is contain within "etc., ..."?